# Implementing a Fisher–Yates shuffle loop is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), but when I test the code below just with an alert, it doesn't seem to loop. It stops after the first time, I think.

```
function scrambleWord() {
    var letterArray = currentWord.split("");
    var m = letterArray.length, t, i;
    while (m) {
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
        t = letterArray[m];
        letterArray[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
    }
    scrambledWord = letterArray.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array`, `i` and `currentWord` were never defined anywhere:

```
function shuffleWord(word) {
  var array = word.split('');
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array.join('');
}
```

Comment: the currentWord is defined but not inside this function but outside of it. sorry i didnt make it clear. and i is defined here "var m =letterArray.length, t, i;" and isnt the array just created literal way ?

Comment: @user2316675: `i` is defined, but it isn't given a value anywhere. What do you mean by`*created literal way*?

Comment: from w3schools: Literal: var myCars=["Saab","Volvo","BMW"]; but in code above it populated by the letters from the string currentWord

Comment: @user2316675: But where is `array` defined?

Comment: oh shit. im the best. thanks it was suppose to be letterArray... took me while to spot =( much appreciate your patience with me!

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't defined `currentWord` or `array`.

Troubleshooting begins in your browser's developer console.